# In snowflake, how to convert varchar column into date format, so that i need to sum the value on monthly basics using date_trunc function

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

In a Table

[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjGIr.png)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtP3h.png)

i need to sum the value on monthly basics using date_trunc function, but i couldn't able to convert the column

Comment: Please don't link to images. Add all relevant information directly to your question, preferably as editable text

Comment: @Ponmathi, There is a record for "20-Mar", "50" but the sum of March is 30. Please be careful on sharing the output. There is no year on "20-Mar" but somehow we accept it 2022. So please describe your requirements and assumptions clearly. And as Nick said, don't paste images, paste the text so people doesn't need to rewrite them.

Comment: You can use `TRY_TO_DATE()` but you need to clean your data first. Like @GokhanAtil mentioned, data seems to be unclean.